# SQL query for finding the two teachers who have access to most number of course rooms

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie with sql queries so I have no clue how to create an accurate SQL.

I tried my best but I literally cannot find any similar example online, please help me out here.

The Data Schema as follows:

```
User(userID, username password, email, , userType)

Course(courseID, courseTitle)

Enroll(userID, courseID)
```

course rooms that users can access; note that users include all sorts of users such as teachers and administrators

```
Material(materialID, materialText, teacherUserID, courseID)
```

Question:

Find the two teachers who have access to most number of course rooms.  Should there be a tie break, choose the ones with smaller user IDs.  List the user ID, email, and the number of course rooms that s/he can access for the two teachers.**

The problems are:

1. SELECT userid, email, MIN (userid)
   How can I specifically find the 2 smaller user IDs and which table should I select for finding out the course rooms? Do I have to use COUNT in this case?
2. FROM user JOIN enroll ON (user.usertype=enroll.userid)
   As the enroll_table cannot identify whether the userID is teacher or administrator, if I use JOIN, can I find the the result that I want?
3. WHERE....
   I don't know how to specifically find two teachers AND make sure they have tie break
4. Do I have to use GROUP BY and ORDER BY as well?

Comment: Add some sample data from your tables with expected output.

Comment: The `enroll` table has a many to one relationship to both `users` and `courses` (which I assume to be synonymous with rooms). So it contains your answer. Find the `count(*)` of relationships for each person in `users`, that has `userType` teacher. For the latter you'll need a join of table `enroll` with the table `user`. Try writing this join based on your course materials, the mysql online help or internet searches and we can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw your attempted query. Look up how to format the code, so it stands out from the text. But you started about right. While we don't have the full info, try the following: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
select user.userid,user.username, count(*) as cnt 
from enroll 
join user on user.userid=enroll.userid
where user.usertype="teacher"
group by user.userid
order by cnt DESC;
```

[image]

So Mary teaches three courses and comes out ahead. Since you want only the top two you can add the line `LIMIT 2` to just get the two most prolific teachers.

The part that is hardest to understand for beginners is the `group by` clause, which generates aggregation, and which requires something like a `count(*)` clause in the first line. Read up on this separately and make yourself an even smaller example so you understand this well.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping and explanation!! I altered something and it works at the end:)

Answer (score 1):

kenken068 also asked for a "tie break" using the userid so maybe the "order by" should be

```
order by cnt DESC, userid ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! but the results are just the same

Answer (score 0):

```
Select teacheruserID, count(courseID) from material 
group by teacheruserID;
```

This will give you the count of courses the teachers have access to.

Then Simply order it in descending with the help of order by desc clause.
and the select `TOP 2` with `TOP` Keyword

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1?
Limit to 2 based on the order on total. And also userid as tie braker.

Problem 2?
That info should be in User.userType
But then you need to know which userType is used for the teachers.
However, teachers have Material?

Problem 3?
See problem 1.

Problem 4?
Not always. But to calculate a total, a count is often used together with a group by.

```
SELECT
 u.userID,
 u.email,
 COUNT(DISTINCT e.courseID) as TotalCourses
FROM `User` AS u
LEFT JOIN `Enroll` AS e
  ON u.userID = e.userID
WHERE u.userID IN (SELECT DISTINCT teacherUserID FROM `Material`)
GROUP BY u.userID, u.email
ORDER BY TotalCourses DESC, u.userID
LIMIT 2
```